# How can I use NTLM functionality with Apache tomacat?

Tags: tomcat, ntlm

I want to use windows NTLM with apache tomcat.
Anyone who's already used it, please give me some information, I am new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use NTLM, instead of Kerberos? Both are supported by Windows AD but the latter is more secure and supported by Java natively. See this question for how to setup, he is very close to get it working :)

[How do I get JNDIRealm in Tomcat to use Kerberos auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422012/how-do-i-get-jndirealm-in-tomcat-to-use-kerberos-auth)

If you really want use NTLM, you have to use JCIFS filter

http://jcifs.samba.org/

Answer (score 1):

There's a link from the [tomcat wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows) to a [SAMBA article](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) explaining how you can add a filter to your webapp to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Using kerberos requires that you get your server a key from the domain administrators. In some cases, this may not be possible.

jcifs code seems to work well enough, although the jcifs people say they're [not interested](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) in supporting NTLM http filter any more. 
I recently made an NTLM filter using jcifs which can authenticate against either of two domains.